# Reshaping pandas dataframe with unstack()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to reshape pandas DataFrame so that one of the columns would be unstacked to 'broader'. Once I proceed with unstack() new column levels occure but I seem to be unable to re-arrange the headers the way I want.

Firstly, I have following df:

```
from pandas import *

fList = [['Packs', 'Brablik', 'Holesovice', '2017', 100],
         ['Decorations', 'Drapp-design', 'Holesovice', '2017', 150],
         ['Decorations', 'Klapetkovi', 'Holesovice', '2017', 200],
         ['Decorations', 'Lezecké dárky', 'Fler', '2017', 100],
         ['Decorations', 'PP', 'Other', '2017', 350],
         ['Decorations', 'Pavlimila', 'Akce', '2017', 20],
         ['Decorations', 'Pavlimila', 'Holesovice', '2017', 50],
         ['Decorations', 'Wiccare', 'Holesovice', '2017', 70],
         ['Toys', 'Klára Vágnerová', 'Holesovice', '2017', 100],
         ['Toys', 'Lucie Polonyiová', 'Holesovice', '2017', 80],
         ['Dresses', 'PP', 'Other', '2018', 200]]

df = DataFrame(fList, columns = ['Section', 'Seller', 'Store', 'Selected_period', 'Total_pieces'])
```

This produces:
[image]

Consequently I reshape it like:

```
df = df.set_index(['Section', 'Seller', 'Store', 'Selected_period']).unstack(level = -1)
df = df.fillna(0)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

That outputs:

[image]

However, I would like to have just following columns in the final dataframe: Section, Seller, Store, 2017, 2018. I still fail to re-arrange it so that I would get the output I want, despite I tried to adopt solutions posted [here](http://nikgrozev.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554525/pandas-unstacking-one-column-of-a-dataframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233488/pandas-drop-a-level-from-a-multi-level-column-index). Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the output that you *do* want?

Comment: The output I am after is the last posted but with different columns, there must be first column Section, second column Seller, third column Store, fourth column 2018, fifth column 2018..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you seem to just be missing a `reset_index()` call. Try this:

```
df = df.set_index(['Section', 'Seller', 'Store', 'Selected_period']).unstack(level = -1).fillna(0)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0).rename('')
df = df.reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to get some kind of concatenated column names for 2017 and 2018 so that they would be named "Total_pieces: 2017" and "Total_pieces: 2018"?

Comment: Yes. Not very elegant, but in the solution above you can replace `df.columns.droplevel(0).rename('')` by `df.columns.get_level_values(0) + ': ' + df.columns.get_level_values(1)`

Comment: Thank you! This also worked on pd.pivot_table() as well.